# How do I move the bootmgr folder to a different drive?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, boot, bcdedit

I'd like to delete a FAT16 partition that only has boot information on it. I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2.

I've used BCDEdit to examine the boot configuration(output below).

I'm just unclear how to move the bootmgr from F: to C:.

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=F:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {59d84d8a-0888-11e0-9d9c-91c956e448ed}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {59d84d8c-0888-11e0-9d9c-91c956e448ed}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {59d84d8a-0888-11e0-9d9c-91c956e448ed}
nx                      OptOut
```

[image: Disk Management 1]
[image: Disk Management 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably better for superuser. in fact: https://superuser.com/questions/32164/easiest-way-to-copy-or-clone-boot-partition-onto-new-hard-drive

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/240085/moving-the-location-of-bcd-store/240092#240092 BCDBoot is what I needed.